# How can I pass a Vector from C++ to Fortran?

Tags: c++, fortran, gfortran

I have a code in C++ and I would like to call some functions in Fortran. I have the following function

```
Vector3d CWLiDAR__get_position(CWLiDAR* This)
{
    return This->get_position();
}
```

There is a wrapper in Fortran:

```
module CWLiDAR_module
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding
    implicit none

    private
    type CWLiDAR_type
        private
        type(C_ptr) :: object = C_NULL_ptr
    end type CWLiDAR_type

    interface    
        function C_CWLiDAR__get_position (this)  result(pos)  bind(C, name="CWLiDAR__get_position")
            import
            type(C_ptr), value                          :: this
            real(C_double), intent(out), dimension(*)   :: pos
        end function C_CWLiDAR__get_position
    end interface

    interface get_position
        module procedure CWLiDAR__get_position
    end interface get_position


    public :: get_position, CWLiDAR_type


    contains

    function CWLiDAR__get_position(this) result(pos)
        type(CWLiDAR_type), intent(in)                  :: this
        double precision, dimension(0:3)                :: pos

        pos = C_CWLiDAR__get_position(this%object)
    end function CWLiDAR__get_position

end module CWLiDAR_module
```

However I am getting the following compilation error:

```
     function C_CWLiDAR__get_position (this)  result(pos)  bind(C, name="CWL
                                                            1
Error: Assumed size array at (1) must be a dummy argument
         function C_CWLiDAR__get_position (this)  result(pos)  bind(C, name="CWL
        1
Error: Assumed size array at (1) must be a dummy argument
```

How can I pass a Vector3D to Fortran?

Comment: Perhaps `.data ()`

Comment: Does not help, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions which return arrays are NOT interoperable with C. You cannot call such a function from Fortran. At least not portably using `bind(C)`.

If it was possible (but it isn't!) the syntax would have to be

```
   interface    
        function C_CWLiDAR__get_position (this)  result(pos)  bind(C, name="CWLiDAR__get_position")
            import
            type(C_ptr), value                          :: this
            real(C_double),  dimension(some_number)   :: pos
        end function C_CWLiDAR__get_position
    end interface
```

The compiler is complaining that neither `intent`, nor `dimension(*)` is allowed for function results in Fortran. That is the reason for the error message.

Comment: I should implement as a routine?

Comment: Yes, make it an out parameter in C++.

Comment: Yes subroutine, as vector FUNCTIONs are Fortran and there is no BIND(C), so use SUBROUTINE.